# Appending a PHP string for SQL request

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a PHP function that uses a PDO to call an SQL query. I'm trying to find a match for strings using the LIKE operator in SQL but that requires the string to begin and end with '% '.

Now my search term comes from a PHP string and I was wondering if there was any way to append that to include the '% '. At the moment I tried adding it separately but it doesn't seem to be functioning.

```
function searchBay($address) {
// STUDENT TODO:
// Change lines below with code to retrieve the Bays with similar address from the database
// - - C H E C K - - 
$db = connect();
$sql = "SELECT p.bayid, p.site, p.address, p.avail_wk_start ||' '|| p.avail_wk_end ||' '|| p.avail_wend_start ||' '|| p.avail_wend_end AS avail 
                FROM PeerPark.ParkBay p
                WHERE p.address LIKE (% ':address' %')";
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchObject();
    $stmt->closecursor();
}   catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error searching for bays: " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
}
print_r($row);
return $row; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query end to this:

```
p.address LIKE :address
```

And send the parameter like this:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':address', "%$address%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Absolutely legend.